# Chartjs real time graph x axis movement

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js

I want to display a chart with Chartjs which displays real time data and slowly scrolls along the x axis, I have tried it here with js fiddle and it just jumps like crazy up and down: https://jsfiddle.net/rsnufpq7/

The graph should just move to the left side with the old points out of view without this animation like in the second example here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 5,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 5,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 59, 80, 0, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};

var zero = 7;
function adddata(){

   var value = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);;
      myLineChart.data.labels.push(zero);
      myLineChart.data.labels.splice(0, 1);
  myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data.splice(0, 1);
  myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(value); 


  myLineChart.update();
  zero++;
}



   setInterval(function(){
   adddata();
    },1000);

var option = {
    showLines: true
};
var myLineChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
    data:data,
  options:option
});
```

Comment: I'm also trying to do this same thing. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: The best solution I found is this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/51687297/9180619

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected, only thing that you are missing is your y axis does not have range defined and it is being dynamically adjusted.

In order to achieve this I have extended your options to look like this.

```
var option = {
  showLines: true,
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      display: true,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero:true,
        min: 0,
        max: 100  
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

I have defined min and max value for y axis and it is not jumping anymore.

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xzja4tL/1/)

Comment: This doesn't refer to what I have asked, is it possible to disable the animation and just slide the graph to the left side?

Comment: @Max it is regarding bouncing up and down part only. regarding animation, i have found out only how to disable the animations, but not how to make them slide from right to left. to disable animation use `animation: {duration: 0},`. Here is a link to updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kukicvladimir/3xzja4tL/4/).